# Relation between sequence of call of fork() and exec()

Tags: multithreading, unix, fork, exec

I got the difference between fork() and exec() system call

A program may be multithreaded--i.e., may contain more than one thread, say T1, T2, andd T3. Now if a particular thread of a program--say T2--executes fork(), a new duplicate (except with a different PID, PC, stack) process will be created with two possiblities:

1. The process that has been created will contain all the threads T1, T2, T3.
2. The process that has been created will contain only the thread that executed fork(), i.e., T2. It is a single threaded process

So there are two version of fork() for the above scenario.

- Point 1 denotes exec()
- Point 2 denotes fork()

Am I correct?

#### Question

If the sequence of the call is like

- fork() is immediately followed by exec()
- exec() is immediately followed by fork()

Can anyone please provide a practical example of above two cases?

Comment: exec () -> fork () is actually impossible, because exec () returns only when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct?

Not really. The fork concept is a UNIX-ism. If you call fork() you should should get an almost exact copy of the of the original process. The only different is that the return value of fork in the parent process is the process idea of the child process while the turn value of fork in the child process is 0.

```
if (fork () == 0)
{
   // In the child process
   // Usually call exec here.
}
else
{
   //  In the parent process
}
```

On UNIX variants, you should get copies of all the threads of the parent in the child. Other systems may have different behaviors.

A call to fork() is usually immediately followed by a call to exec (or one of its variants) to load a different program. There is rarely any use to simply fork copies of the parent program and just keep it running (exception: this is common in server applications handling network connections).

> Can anyone please provide a practical example of above two cases?

First, this sequence does not normally occur:

> exec() is immediately followed by fork()

This is the normal use of fork:

> fork() is immediately followed by exec()

For example, consider a command line shell. You type in something like this:

```
$ ./someapplication param1 param2
```

In order to start `someapplication`, the shell needs to create a new process. It does that by calling fork(). This just creates a copy of the shell (not very useful). The the child process copy of the shell calls exec to run `someapplication`.

Yes, this is confusing. In most operating systems you specify the executable when you create a child process. This fork system made sense in the days of the PDP computer and it made sense for certain network programming applications when viewed in the context of the limitations of the UNIX system.

For example, under the RSX operating system that ran on PDP's, there were provisions for software interrupts. A single process could handle multiple network connections and devices. You would queue an I/O request to a device (non-blocking) then receive a software interrupt when the I/O completed. Thus, a single process could have I/O requests pending on multiple devices.

UNIX was much less sophisticated. All I/O was blocking. Where in RSX, you would normally have one process controlling multiple devices, in UNIX you'd have one process per device (keep in mind this is before the days of threads—although blocking I/O calls are still problematic with eunuchs threads). The fork model fit the UNIX way of doing things and provides a simple means of creating a process. In RSX there was much more overhead for process creation.